# How to perform sub pattern matches with neo4j.Apoc?

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching, neo4j-apoc

I have the query:

```
MATCH (a:vertex {label: 'a'})<-->(b:vertex {label: 'b'})
MATCH (a)<-->(e:vertex {label: 'e'})
MATCH (b)<-->(c:vertex {label: 'c'})
MATCH (b)<-->(e:vertex {label: 'e'})
MATCH (c)<-->(d:vertex {label: 'd'}) 
MATCH (d)<-->(e)
MATCH (d)<-->(a)
return a,b,c,d,e
```

And a graph of 50.000 vertices and 10.000.000 edges.
It only has labels a,b,c,d,e,f in total, and I know that this match exists.

I have installed the `neo4j.apoc` plugin in order to utilize the 8 cores on my machine, and I tried the following query already:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (a:vertex {label: 'a'})<-->(b:vertex {label: 'b'})
MATCH (a)<-->(e:vertex {label: 'e'})
MATCH (b)<-->(c:vertex {label: 'c'})
MATCH (b)<-->(e:vertex {label: 'e'})
MATCH (c)<-->(d:vertex {label: 'd'}) 
MATCH (d)<-->(e)
MATCH (d)<-->(a)
return a,b,c,d,e",
"return DISTINCT([ID(a),ID(b),ID(c),ID(d),ID(e)]) AS LIST", {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

This query only utilizes a few of the cores, and it basically never returns the result, it just processes forever. I have been looking at
the function `apoc.path.subgraphAll(startNode <id>Node/list, {maxLevel, relationshipFilter, labelFilter, bfs:true, filterStartNode:true, limit:-1}) yield nodes, relationships`

But since I am very new to NEO4J and also Apoc of course, I actually don't understand how to fill out these relationships. Is there someone who knows about this stuff and can point me in the right direction?

Edit: I have a custom java graph implementation that does this in parallel and finishes in about 600 ms, I was expecting NEO4J to finish it even faster, but because a query only uses 1 thread, it takes a long time, which is why I have been looking into Apoc. I am also open to use other things than Apoc, maybe my query could be optimized using just NEO4J and finish way faster. I created a index on :vertex(label) so at least that part does a index seek.

Edit2: 
This query should do the same, and is obviously prettier:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (a:vertex {label:'a'})--(b:vertex {label: 'b'})--(c:vertex {label: 'c'})--(d:vertex {label: 'd'})--(e:vertex {label: 'e'}) WHERE (c)<-->(d) AND (b)--(e) AND (d)--(a) 
RETURN a,b,c,d,e",
"return DISTINCT([ID(a),ID(b),ID(c),ID(d),ID(e)]) AS LIST", {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

But it is still never stops processing, i even adjust the graph to 10k vertices and 5 million edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need Apoc for this, I had misunderstood cypher syntax, i thought that (a)<-->(b) meant that a and b needed a bidirectional relationship. But it is actually just an anonymous relationship. 
So I optimized it to this:

```
MATCH (a:vertex {label:'a'})-->(b:vertex {label: 'b'})-->(c:vertex {label: 'c'})-->(d:vertex {label: 'd'})-->(e:vertex {label: 'e'}) WHERE (d)-->(a) AND (b)-->(e) AND (d)-->(e)  WITH a,b,c,d,e
MATCH (a)<--(b)<--(c)<--(d)<--(e:vertex {label: 'e'}) WHERE (d)<--(a) AND (b)<--(e) AND (d)<--(e)  WITH a,b,c,d,e
return DISTINCT([ID(a),ID(b),ID(c),ID(d),ID(e)])
```

In order to filter on the edges pointing in both directions, making the numbers of estimated rows in the query plan much much lower, and now finishes in 12000 ms

Comment: You can cut down on a few things, as some of your checks are already fulfilled by your matches. In the first line, `AND (d)-->(e)` can be dropped, that's captured in your MATCH pattern. In the second line, you don't need `(e:vertex {label: 'e'})` since that was already established from your previous MATCH to `e`. Just use `(d)<--(e)` here at the end of that pattern. In the WHERE clause, you can drop `AND (d)<--(e)` since that's already taken care of in the MATCH. And of course make sure you have an index on `:vertex(label)`

Comment: Arg yeah, of course, I was just too fast on the trigger :) Thanks!